# how to use if condition to include in nunjucks?

Tags: nunjucks

so I have a page parameter sent from server.So I set the currentPage to be event if it is event otherwise default. I'm trying to include only when page is default.

The following code works when current page is not event i.e default but for event page it sends error as follows:

```
{% set currentPage = 'event' if page === 'event' else 
            'default' %}

        {% include 'partials/default-scripts.njk' if currentPage === 'default' %}
```

Error:

```
Template render error: 
 Error: The `name` parameter is not specified:
```

I'm not sure what is wrong really.

Answer (score 5):

```
{% set currentPage = ('event' if page === 'event' else 'default') %}

{% if currentPage == 'default' %}
{% include 'partials/default-scripts.njk' %}
{% endif %}
or 
{% include ('partials/default-scripts.njk' if currentPage == 'default' else 'dummy') %}
```

Where `dummy` is an empty template.